# Replace a model sublist by another list (MongoDB or Scala)

Tags: mongodb

My document structure looks like:

```
{
   "name":"CategoryChildLevel2",
   "parentId":"2",
   "otherAttribute":"anyVal",
   "breadcrumb":[
      {
         "name":"RootCategory",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {
         "name":"CategoryChildLevel1",
         "id":"2"
      },
      {
         "name":"CategoryChildLevel2",
         "id":"3"
      }
   ]
}
```

What I want is to be able to run a query that says:

Replace the breadcrumb arrays that begins with

```
      {
         "name":"RootCategory",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {
         "name":"CategoryChildLevel1",
         "id":"2"
      }
```

replace this subsequence by

```
      {
         "name":"RootCategory",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {
         "name":"AnotherCategory",
         "id":"4"
      }
      {
         "name":"AnotherCategory2",
         "id":"5"
      }
```

so that the final result is

```
{
   "name":"CategoryChildLevel2",
   "parentId":"2",
   "otherAttribute":"anyVal",
   "breadcrumb":[
      {
         "name":"RootCategory",
         "id":"1"
      },
      {
         "name":"AnotherCategory",
         "id":"4"
      },
      {
         "name":"AnotherCategory2",
         "id":"5"
      },
      {
         "name":"CategoryChildLevel2",
         "id":"3"
      }
   ]
}
```

Can we do this in MongoDB? Or at least retrieve the items that we should update (`array startsWith` query), with normal query langage or map/reduce?

Comment: Not really answering your question directly but I have a very similar structure  - retail categories in a hierarchy used in a Play app, stored in Mongo.  What I do is store them in a Tree (implementation from Scalaz) and calculate breadcrumbs on the fly.  The scalaz tree works very efficiently so hasn't needed the optimization of storing a path along with each node.  To move a category I update the new parent with an additional child, and update the old parent with the child removed.  It might be worth asking yourself if you really need to store the path (breadcrumb) in mongo.

Comment: @BrianSmith I don't understand, are you storing the whole hierarchy on a single document? Because actually I don't want to do that. And I currently compute the breadcrumbs on the fly, which involve a recursion of mongo requests which I'd like to avoid. Without loading the whole tree I don't see how using a Tree can help

Comment: Sorry I was unclear - when I said "store them in a Tree" I should have said "load them from Mongo into a Tree".  Each category is a separate record in the mongo collection, but held in memory in the Tree structure.  The breadcrumb is calculated from the tree in memory whenever needed.

Comment: My tree can become quite huge and I'd like to avoid this solution :)

Comment: what about using subtrees? Just an Idea and based on the normal fact that upper levels are not changing very often. There are also several Tree Solutions on mongoDB Slides and in the Wiki. Have a look here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Trees+in+MongoDB

Comment: already read that @Marc but my tree can be huge and the top of the tree can move

Comment: What i huge? Millions of Leafs or Categories? What are you doing with that tree except showing Breadcrumbs? I guess it is not a topic tree for a catalogue right? Are you Changing the Structure all the time or just "Names". And why you have to changing it? If you refer to breadcrumbs, then a volatile Path might not end in a good user experience ;)

Comment: My usecase is kind of a filesystem, with a lot of folders and files in it. Folders can be moved, and there are direct links to the content so when a top folder is moved, and a child is accessed, the child breadcrumb must be available

Answer (score 1):

As of Mongo 2.2, you can use array [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) in the query selector of an update to do this:

```js
db.test.update({
    'breadcrumb.0.id': '1',
    'breadcrumb.1.id': '2'
}, {
    $set: {
        'breadcrumb.1': {
            name: "AnotherCategory",
            id: "4"
        }
    }
}, {multi: true})
```

In prior versions you had to do this with a [`$where`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/) query selector in an `update` like this:

```js
db.test.update({
    'breadcrumb.id': '2',
    // Check the name fields as well here, if necessary.
    $where: "this.breadcrumb.length > 1 && this.breadcrumb[0].id === '1' && this.breadcrumb[1].id === '2'"
}, {
    $set: {
        'breadcrumb.1': {
            name: "AnotherCategory",
            id: "4"
        }
    }
}, { multi: true})
```

The `'breadcrumb.id': '2'` component of the query will help with the performance as it will limit the number of docs the slow `$where` will have to operate on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try that soon! I didn't know we could use "where breadcrumb[0].id === x". But in your set you use breadcrumb.1, is it normal to not use breadcrumb[1] = {object} ?

Comment: `$where` uses straight JavaScript syntax, but `$set` uses its own syntax for array updates.  However, I found that in 2.2 you can do this without a `$where`.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I updated my usecase, because I think your answer doesn't tell me how to do handle a change in the array size. Notice the new "AnotherCategory2"

Comment: That's a very different use case.  I don't think there's a way to insert a new array element at a given index in an `update`.  You'd have to manually iterate over the collection in code, modify `breadcrumb` array as needed, and save each doc individually.

Comment: thanks, at least there's a way to retrieve elements to update :)